# Annoying Fan noise vs slow down

Tags: performance, fan, noise

I was in a situation where when I would scroll or navigate through Google Drive, there would be a slowdown while a fan that had been silent revved up. It would also keep me awake at night.

So today I researched it and ended up taking all my fans off of "smart fan" in the bios and just setting them all at 100% all the time.

Goodbye slowdown. I can flip around through apps and web pages without that delay that drove me up the wall.

But now, even though I have all SSD, I have not realized the dream of a quiet PC.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds or am I now stuck with this constant loud purring because I want responsive web pages and apps, etc?

Comment: Laptop or desktop?  Replacing the fans with quieter fans would be an option, as well as keeping the system in a cooler location so you don't need active cooling.  The expectation that an SSD is going to be all you need for a passively cooled system is a bit unrealistic . . .

Comment: What does your SSD have to do with this problem?

Comment: @ernie, desktop. I have no problem with active cooling.

Comment: @Ramhound, nothing. They are part of the ultimate goal of having a quiet PC. "Even tho I have all SSDs", meaning, even tho my SSDs are not making any noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a computer fan is making an annoying noise, it is often also the case that the computer is running hotter than it needs to run due to a mechanical problem with a worn out fan. Replacing the fan not only eliminates the noise, but may also lower your computer's temperatures because the replacement fan may also run faster in addition to running more quietly.

Comment: The chassis fan and GPU fan are both new. The GPU fan is very quiet. It might be the CPU fan then. Whatever it is, when I had it on smart fan it was only running when the system was making an effort to do something. It's the noise that it has always made; I have just gotten more picky lately about noise. I don't think it's noisier than it was on day one. Thanks.